# docker-compose as vagrant provider?

Tags: mysql, apache, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

We are currently using Docker to containerise our applications for the purpose of having our CI server running tests and (soon) deployment to production.

We are using vagrant to keep a consistent development environment by having vagrant use docker as a provider. So our developers can simply vagrant up on any machine (windows, mac and linux - we use a mixture) and get a consistently provisioned virtualbox running our containerised application with Docker.

We are kind of new to all this, but it is my understanding that this is pretty standard stuff.

However, we want to utilise the container separation with docker-compose. Our Dockerfile currently manages both the web server and the database and, for example, in a live environment we will not need an SQL server as part of our container, but this will need to be provisioned under the development environment. Is this the correct way of going about this? If so, is it possible? If not, I have probably misunderstood, and anyone who can enlighten me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: So after doing some further reading, it seems like docker-compose DIRECT is the way to go and is essentially an alternative to vagrant. My understanding now is that a live environment will not use docker-compose but instead launch the required docker containers directly, whilst docker-compose can be run directly for development environments. I'm hesitant to do this, as the workflow for running docker-compose, particularly on non-Linux machines, seems a lot more complicated than just doing vagrant up?

Comment: when you say `Our Dockerfile currently manages both the web server and the database` you mean your docker-compose.yml ? There is a difference between the two and using good vocabulary is important to be understood.

Comment: Actually you need to separate things, this is all the philosophy of using docker. So you can have a same docker-compose.yml in which you define your web server and your SQL server as a dependance for your web server. This way, when you run your container, the container for your database service will run automatically (but still separately) and your web server will have access to it.

Comment: @dzof31 Thanks for the response. No, I mean Dockerfile (it is our only file - it provisions a single container with both the apache and mysql). We would like to split this up into two containers using a docker-compose file (which I understand is best practice for obvious reasons). Not sure how this fits into provisioning the machine with vagrant. Thanks!

Comment: @dzof31 See edit.

Comment: I never used docker for non-linux machines and i think it can be complicated to find help in this area. Anyway, docker works the same way in development environment than production. What you can do is to properly config your dockerfile with a command `CMD` at the end of dockerfile to run your web server for example, and generate a docker-compose for each environment (you can override the command in dockerfile if you want to).

Comment: In my company we use ECS from amazon, and the task is quite easy, we create some task templates and for each delivery we use the task template to create a new task definition

Comment: The philosophy is the same i think. I dont understand the need to use vagrant by the way.

Comment: There is some tools which i recommend to monitor your docker containers https://github.com/docker/kitematic 
https://github.com/bcicen/ctop

Comment: @dzof31 Since we're using a mix of windows, mac and linux machines, does it not make sense to use vagrant to ensure a consistent dev environment?

Comment: You need to understand what are differences between containers and virtual machines https://www.solidfire.com/blog/containers-vs-vms/. In a personal point of view, i prefer working on a containerized platform rather than a VM. You have much more possibilities and setting up things have too many benefits on the long term. You can share ressources ( a little example, let's suppose in each VM you have a Mysql service + 1 database, with docker you can have only one Mysql container for all your databases and the other containers can access to it with good permissions )

Comment: It's obvious if you want to migrate from vagrant to docker, there is a cost in doing that. The question is, in how much time would you be able to make it profitable to your business  ?